# Jquery On Click Color

Tags: javascript, jquery, colors, onclick

I am trying to change the color of my div using jquery, my page already has jQuery and a JavaScript function called getBallColor defined on it. But I am not sure how to complete this task, can somebody help.

Codepen URL: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XJVRrL

```
HTML:
<div id="myBall">
</div>



CSS:
#myBall{
width:150px;
height:150px;
border-radius:100px;
line-height:100px;
background:purple;
margin: auto;
position: absolute;
top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
}


Javascript:
$(window).load(function(){
$("#myBall").click(function (){

});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a class called red for example in your css

```
.red { background-color: red; }
```

Then use the click eventhandler to toggle the class

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myBall").click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('red');
    });
});
```

**EDIT** I just saw the part about the function that you mentioned, here is a better answer:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myBall").click(function(){
        $(this).css('background-color', getBallColor());
    });
});
```

This assumes that the function getBallColor() returns a valid color as a string.

Answer (score 1):

Use `'background-color'` instead of `'background'`.

```
#myBall{
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
  border-radius:100px;
  line-height:100px;
  background-color: purple;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
}
```

Then you can just change the specific CSS property:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $("#myBall").click(function (){
        $(this).css("background-color", "lime");
    });
});
```

See your [CodePan](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ByJRoY) improved: